# How can I remove Excel menu in web apps in Share Point 2013?

Tags: excel-services, office-web-apps, powerpivot

I use SharePoint 2013 and I use Power Pivot Service.
When I open an Excel Report, I see this report :

[image]

How can I remove Excel menu(File/Open In Excel / Data/...) from this report?

Comment: Robert ..i'm looking for the same solution.Is this possible?

Comment: Has anyone found an answer to this?